# Removing All Items Under A Node Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to remove all the children under a node. Is there a way to delete all the items under a node? The structure is like:

```
lastMessages
  - mainId
    - timestampedId
      - keys:values
```

What I want to do is, by using `mainId`, delete all the items under it. Actually there's only one `timestampedId` at a time as this is for lastMessages. That's why I thought I should delete all items under `mainId` just before writing my new value. Is there a way to achieve that; or is there any better ways than I thought?

```
let ref = Firebase(url: path)
let myRef = ref.childByAppendingPath(mainId)   

// how to delete all items under myRef?
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply call `myRef.removeValue()`

Explained in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/save-data#update_specific_fields)

> The simplest way to delete data is to call removeValue on a reference to the location of that data.